# How to assure that websocket was opened from my webpage

Tags: security, webserver, websocket

So, the question is:
Is there a way to be sure that the client who is trying to connect to my websocket server, is doing this from the webpage that I provide, and not from any other page, or script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A malicious user/program can connect to this websocket and there is nothing you can do about it (Period end of story).   However, the same-origin policy for WebSockets should be very similar to that of XHR.  JavaScript on another domain cannot access a WebSocket on your domain unless you explicitly allow it.   So this means if someone where to redistribute your content,  they would have to use a cross-domain proxy.

Comment: "JavaScript on another domain cannot access a WebSocket on your domain." - This is definitely possible in fact. You just need to check the `Sec-WebSocket-Origin` header value.

Comment: @pimvdb  Exactly my point, the rules are nearly identical for both features.   With XHR you use the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

Comment: To clarify, Javascript running in an uncompromised and well-behaved  browser cannot affect the value of Sec-WebSocket-Origin which holds the value of the original site the page was loaded from (allowing your server to only allow certain origination points). However, if you had Javascript running in Node.js as a WebSocket client, it could set the origin value to whatever it wants. The CORS security is for the safety of browser users, not for your server. You need other mechanisms to protect your server.

Comment: @JRicardo000 really the only defense against automation is a captcha. Or perhaps you should consider changing your business model to reflect the laws of technology.