# Is my websocket's server origin checking safe?

Tags: php, security, websocket

I'm using https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket/

I can allow some domains, and I have allowed `localhost` and a domain which points to my local server. But I wonder if someone else which has a server on his computer can connect to my websocket (through my domain) using an script in his localhost server.

Here is the relevant code:

-> server/server.php

```
$server->setAllowedOrigin('localhost');
$server->setAllowedOrigin('mydomain.com');
```

-> server/lib/WebSocket/Connection.php

```
// check origin:
if($this->server->getCheckOrigin() === true)
{
    $origin = (isset($headers['Sec-WebSocket-Origin'])) ? $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Origin'] : false;
    $origin = (isset($headers['Origin'])) ? $headers['Origin'] : $origin;
    if($origin === false)
    {
        $this->log('No origin provided.');
        $this->sendHttpResponse(401);
        stream_socket_shutdown($this->socket, STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
        $this->server->removeClientOnError($this);
        return false;
    }

    if(empty($origin))
    {
        $this->log('Empty origin provided.');
        $this->sendHttpResponse(401);
        stream_socket_shutdown($this->socket, STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
        $this->server->removeClientOnError($this);
        return false;
    }

    if($this->server->checkOrigin($origin) === false)
    {
        $this->log('Invalid origin provided.');
        $this->sendHttpResponse(401);
        stream_socket_shutdown($this->socket, STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
        $this->server->removeClientOnError($this);
        return false;
    }
}
```

-> server/lib/WebSocket/Server.php

```
public function checkOrigin($domain)
{
    $domain = str_replace('http://', '', $domain);
    $domain = str_replace('https://', '', $domain);
    $domain = str_replace('www.', '', $domain);
    $domain = str_replace('/', '', $domain);

    return isset($this->_allowedOrigins[$domain]);
}

public function setAllowedOrigin($domain)
{
    $domain = str_replace('http://', '', $domain);
    $domain = str_replace('www.', '', $domain);
    $domain = (strpos($domain, '/') !== false) ? substr($domain, 0, strpos($domain, '/')) : $domain;
    if(empty($domain))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $this->_allowedOrigins[$domain] = true;     
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:**

Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want that everybody can connect to the websocket but only if they are at my domain (or my localhost), something like Same Origin Policy in AJAX.

My worry is that if I allow localhost, maybe all other localhost in other computers will be allowed too.

Comment: _maybe all other localhost in other computers will be allowed too_. No, that's not a problem. The IP is being converted to a name by your server, and `localhost` is only for connections from `127.0.0.1`, which is the loopback address.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. But the origin is provided by a header, and my server shouldn't be analysing my headers trying to convert IPs and domains if I don't tell it to do that, isn't it?

Comment: It comes from the header of the IP packet, which is used to implement the TCP/IP transport. If you're using hostnames in your allow list, it has to convert these names to IPs using DNS.

Comment: @Barmar But then it would be the same executing the script from localhost than from 127.0.0.1, because it's the same; but my websocket doesn't think so and blocks the connection from 127.0.0.1 because I have only allowed from localhost. Then, my server isn't converting IPs nor hostnames.

Comment: I thought you were worried about it allowing too much, not blocking things the real localhost. Are you sure the connection is really from localhost, and not from the local machine's configured IP? It will only be _from_ localhost if the connection is made _to_ localhost.

Comment: @Barmar No, it's not a problem if connections from 127.0.0.1 are blocked, because I always use localhost but not 127.0.0.1. But I was saying that they are the same thing but one is allowed and the other isn't. Then, `$headers['Origin']` shows the domain's name where the client is, but there is no IP/domain conversion. Then, if someone connects to my websocket from his localhost, `$headers['Origin']` will be localhost, and it will be allowed, isn't it?

Comment: And yes, I connected to my websocket using localhost and 127.0.0.1, not my local network IP nor my public Internet IP.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake, I thought we were talking about checks at IP layer, not websockets headers. I didn't read your code carefully.

Comment: So I also have a similar conundrum. Did you resolve this in any way?

Comment: @outrunthewolf No, I think it can't be resolved. I have been thinking mecanisms to add more protection, like requiring the client to connect to different ports following a certain sequence before allowing the connection. Maybe that could block random attacks, but clients must be able to connect, so everybody would see the sequence and be able to use a customized attack.

Comment: And just checking client IP's would not be safe enough I guess?

Comment: @outrunthewolf It depends. In my case I want to allow all IPs, but only if they connect from my domain. But if you only want to allow some trusted static IPs, do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I was worried about allowing connections from all localhost when I wanted to allow only my localhost, i have found that in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605667/how-to-assure-that-websocket-was-opened-from-my-webpage), [kanaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471795/kanaka) said:

> To clarify, Javascript running in an uncompromised and well-behaved
>   browser cannot affect the value of Sec-WebSocket-Origin which holds
>   the value of the original site the page was loaded from (allowing your
>   server to only allow certain origination points). However, if you had
>   Javascript running in Node.js as a WebSocket client, it could set the
>   origin value to whatever it wants. The CORS security is for the safety
>   of browser users, not for your server. You need other mechanisms to
>   protect your server.

Then, my origin checking code is not safe at all; and it doesn't matter if all allow all localhosts because if someone has enough knowledge for connecting to my websocket using his own localhost, it is likely that he could modify the Origin header.

Comment: There is no such thing as "someone else's localhost"

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Well, I mean "someone else's local server", which is accessed using localhost (in his machine).

Comment: that's what I mean, too. *Every* server is "localhost" to itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure, you should add an IP check, analyzing `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`. The origin that is being checked is a text value provided by the client which can easily be forged.

```
if (!in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], array("127.0.0.1", "ip.of.dom.ain")) exit;
```

If you don't want to hardcode the IP address or if that changes frequently, you can use [gethostbyname](http://php.net/gethostbyname) to fetch the IP address for the domain like this. Be aware that this will add a delay to each request when the DNS must be queried for the domain(s) and this way will cause timeouts when your DNS goes down. (the following code could be optimized, of course)

```
$allowed_origins = array('localhost', 'mydomain.com');
$allowed_ips = array();
foreach ($allowed_origins as $domain) {
    $server->setAllowedOrigin($domain);
    $allowed_ips[] = gethostbyname($domain);
}
if (!in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $allowed_ips)) exit;
```

Probably the proper way to do this would be to protect your resource through your web server so that it only accepts requests from the IP addresses you wish to allow (see [deny in Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#deny) or [deny in nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessModule#deny)).

Comment: But I can't do an IP checking because I want that everybody can connect to the websocket but only if they are at my domain... And with `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` (or `deny` in Apache) I can check client's IP, instead of the domain's one, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I understand, I just assumed that you were proxying in a way. Well, then anybody will be able to connect to your websocket, as that is the idea. It doesn't matter if this other person has a server on his machine or not. He could use any program like `curl` to connect to your server. What scenario in particular are you trying to avoid? (why are you speaking about someone with a server?)

Comment: I am speaking about someone with a server because I added localhost to the allowed origin list, then I thought that somebody with a server (localhost on his computer) with a script which connects to my Websocket; and he could do it because the script is executed in his localhost, which matches with my localhost, even if they aren't the same. So, what I want is something like Same Origin Policy in AJAX, allowing only connections from my domain and my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking the `Origin` header, that's enough to enforce something like the Same Origin Policy. The `Origin` header can be spoofed outside of the browser in a custom application like a node WebSocket client, but that doesn't matter, it's the same for normal HTTP requests. SOP is only about browsers.

So checking the `Origin` header isn't about access protection, it's about CSRF protection. Untrusted third party sites won't be allowed to connect to your WebSocket endpoint (with the credentials being automatically sent) if a user is currently logged in.